# Why is my Jenkins missing two configurations？

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, containers, pipeline

Why doesn't my jenkins have "Project Relationship" and "Check File Fingerprint" menus.
Please help me.

Existing menu items:
New Item
People
Build History
Manage Jenkins
My Views

expect:
New Item
People
Build History
Project Relationship
Check File Fingerprint
Manage Jenkins
My Views

I have installed the plugin。

expecting solve the issue.

Comment: New Item 、
 People Build History、
 Manage Jenkins、
 My Views、

Comment: New Item 、People Build History 、Project Relationship 、Check File Fingerprint、 Manage Jenkins、 My Views